# Merge two Collections in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

Need to merge two collections

I have two collections and need to merge them in one collection

these collections was output of two queries using Eloquent

The First Result is like below:

```
Collection {#350
  #items: array:2 [
    0 => {#342
      +"id": 1
      +"code": "C000215"
      +"name": "Mostafa Mohamed Bayomi"
      +"mobile1": "01228902157"
      +"mobile2": ""
      +"CoachServiceCount": 0
      +"CourseServiceCount": 1
      +"CommunicationCount": 0
    }
    1 => {#337
      +"id": 2
      +"code": "C000216"
      +"name": "Sayed Mohamed Bayomi"
      +"mobile1": "01228902158"
      +"mobile2": ""
      +"CoachServiceCount": 0
      +"CourseServiceCount": 2
      +"CommunicationCount": 0
    }
]
}
```

The second query result is like below:

```
Collection {#350
  #items: array:2 [
    0 => {#346
      +"id": 1
      +"code": "C000215"
      +"name": "Mostafa Mohamed Bayomi"
      +"mobile1": "01228902157"
      +"mobile2": ""
      +"CoachServiceAmount": 0.0
    }
    1 => {#340
      +"id": 2
      +"code": "C000216"
      +"name": "Sayed Mohamed Bayomi"
      +"mobile1": "01228902158"
      +"mobile2": ""
      +"CoachServiceAmount": 0.0
    }
]
}
```

I used this code to merge both collections

```
$combined = $firstCollection->merge($secondCollection)
```

I expected below output

```
Collection {#350
  #items: array:2 [
    0 => {#346
      +"id": 1
      +"code": "C000215"
      +"name": "Mostafa Mohamed Bayomi"
      +"mobile1": "01228902157"
      +"mobile2": ""
      +"CoachServiceCount": 0
      +"CourseServiceCount": 1
      +"CommunicationCount": 0
      +"CoachServiceAmount": 0.0
    }
    1 => {#340
      +"id": 2
      +"code": "C000216"
      +"name": "Sayed Mohamed Bayomi"
      +"mobile1": "01228902158"
      +"mobile2": ""
      +"CoachServiceCount": 0
      +"CourseServiceCount": 2
      +"CommunicationCount": 0
      +"CoachServiceAmount": 0.0
    }
]
}
```

But I got this output

```
Collection {#350
  #items: array:4 [
    0 => {#342
      +"id": 1
      +"code": "C000215"
      +"name": "Mostafa Mohamed Bayomi"
      +"mobile1": "01228902157"
      +"mobile2": ""
      +"CoachServiceCount": 0
      +"CourseServiceCount": 1
      +"CommunicationCount": 0
    }
    1 => {#337
      +"id": 2
      +"code": "C000216"
      +"name": "Sayed Mohamed Bayomi"
      +"mobile1": "01228902158"
      +"mobile2": ""
      +"CoachServiceCount": 0
      +"CourseServiceCount": 2
      +"CommunicationCount": 0
    }
    2 => {#346
      +"id": 1
      +"code": "C000215"
      +"name": "Mostafa Mohamed Bayomi"
      +"mobile1": "01228902157"
      +"mobile2": ""
      +"CoachServiceAmount": 0.0
    }
    3 => {#340
      +"id": 2
      +"code": "C000216"
      +"name": "Sayed Mohamed Bayomi"
      +"mobile1": "01228902158"
      +"mobile2": ""
      +"CoachServiceAmount": 0.0
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: From the documentation of merge (https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#method-merge):
If the given items's keys are numeric, the values will be appended to the end of the collection. HTH

Comment: do you mean it will work only when the values are integer ?

Comment: Your item keys are integer (0, 1, 2 etc) which means when you merge, it would result in one collection gets appended to end of the other collection

Answer (score 2):

## The issue

The [documentation for merge()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#method-merge) contains the following text:

> The merge method merges the given array or collection with the original collection. If a string key in the given items matches a string key in the original collection, the given items's value will overwrite the value in the original collection (...) **If the given items's keys are numeric, the values will be appended to the end of the collection**

Meaning `merge()` will not work as you'd expected, since you are using numeric keys.

## Solution 1: non-numeric keys

One solution for your issue would be to use non-numeric values as array keys, this solution will only work if the chosen field (`code` in the example, is the primary key):

```
$firstCollection = $firstCollection->keyBy('code');
$secondCollection = $secondCollection->keyBy('code');
$combined = $firstCollection->merge($secondCollection);

// Optional: reset the array keys to be numeric
$combined = $combined->values();
```

> The keyBy method keys the collection by the given key. If multiple items have the same key, only the last one will appear in the new collection ([source](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#method-keyby))
>
> The values method returns a new collection with the keys reset to consecutive integers ([source](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#method-values))

## Solution 2: zip

If you have the same amount of elements and in the same order in both collections, you could do this:

```
$combined = $firstCollection->zip($secondCollection);
```

> The zip method merges together the values of the given array with the values of the original collection at the corresponding index ([source](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#method-zip))

Answer (score 0):

Use the `union` method: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/collections#method-union

> The union method adds the given array to the collection. If the given array contains keys that are already in the original collection, the original collection's values will be preferred:

```php
$collection = collect([1 => ['a'], 2 => ['b']]);
 
$union = $collection->union([3 => ['c'], 1 => ['d']]);
 
$union->all();
 
// [1 => ['a'], 2 => ['b'], 3 => ['c']]
```